How do I make a proxy to std::vector<vector3f> without exposing the knowledge of vector3f to developers?
I have this code below, what I am doing is making a wrapper or proxy.
Vec3f& Poly2D::operator[](size_t i)
{
    Base::Vector2d& _v = impl->polygon2d->operator[](i);
    Vec3f v(_v.x, _v.y, 0);
    return v;
}

the operator[] returns a reference to element of a vector. however, the return is a Vec3f which I pass out, is there a way to keep the reference to the vector element?
In other words, My question is how to create a wrapper operator[] function to keep the reference to the impl's vector?
Workable code is great!

there is no need for a reference since Vec3f v(_v.x, _v.y, 0); doesn't refer to the object looked up in polygon2d.  Any modification you do to it will change nothing in impl->polygon2d.  Either return Base::Vector2d& and return _v or just return a Vec3f

@NathanOliver yes I know this, but I am doing a wrapper and I need this reference kept or else it defeats all the purpose.

There's nothing to reference though.  v is a distinct object.  Any change you make to it does not affect your internal object.  You either return _v by reference so you can modify the internal data or you need to return some sort of reference wrapper type.

Are you saying you want the x and y in the Vec3f to be references to the Vector2d elements?  That's just not possible, because you don't control those classes.  The Vec3f will contain a snapshot of the values, but they aren't live.

@TimRoberts you are right, and that is the problem. Maybe I should edit the question to be how make a proxy to a vector without exposing the class type of elements.

If you need to treat them sometimes as 2D and sometimes as 3D, why don't you make the original list be a 3D that derives from a 2D?

Also having more than more references to the same object without having the control of the pointed/refereed to object is not a good idea. The object may not live as long as the references and then the references will become dangling.

I wonder why it isn't mentioned yet (or I overlooked it) but: Vec3f v(_v.x, _v.y, 0); is a local variable in operator[](). It's lifetime ends with the next }. Hence, the returned reference becomes dangling after the return v;. This is U.B. (You have to find another solution in any case.)

When your problem involves non-standard library types, you should at least mention which library it is. Is it OpenCV in your case? If so, please, consider adding the relevant tag.

Explicit call to operator functions is not good practice; shorten the code for readability l: auto& v = (*impl->polygon2d)[i];. Next problem: returning a local object by reference leads to dangling and UB. Any decent compiler would warn against it.

struct AlmostButNotQuiteEntirelyUnlikeVec3f {
  AlmostButNotQuiteEntirelyUnlikeVec3f(float& x, float& y) : x(x), y(y), z(0) {}
  float& x;
  float& y;
  float z;
}

and you construct it in your function with
return AlmostButNotQuiteEntirelyUnlikeVec3f(_v.x, _v.y);


Are instances of this type a lukewarm brown liquid?
